# Communications link failure occurs while communicating with MYSQL server using TimerTask

Tags: java, mysql

I have a program that get data from MYSQL DB and send to SAP using JAVA RFC. Then write data back from SAP to MYSQL DB. I am using TimerTask and thread will run every 4 hours. Problem is thread is running great for the first time. But I am getting a communications link failure error since the second run every 4 hours. I think, I am correctly close the connections also.

This is my code.

```
public class CreatePO extends TimerTask {

    private Object[][] itemData; // Object for table data
    RFCHandler handler;

    public CreatePO() {
        handler = new RFCHandler();
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        try {
            getItemFromDB();
            sendDataToSap();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void getItemFromDB() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Connection connection = null;

        DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss");
        Date date = new Date();
        System.out.println(dateFormat.format(date));

        String queryOne = "SELECT reference_no, vendor_acc_no, date, mat_no,"
                + "po_qty, po_unit_measure, rate, order_price_unit, plant, user_name, email_id "
                + "FROM tbl_po_data WHERE status <> 'X'";

        try {
            pooler = DBPool_POSMS.getInstance();
            dataSource1 = pooler.getDataSource();

        } catch (Exception e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {

            connection = dataSource1.getConnection();
            connection.setAutoCommit(false);

            Statement st = connection.createStatement();
            ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(queryOne);

            int lineitem = 0;

            try {
                rs.last();
                rcount = rs.getRow();
                rs.beforeFirst();

            } catch (Exception ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }

            itemData = new Object[11][rcount];

            while (rs.next()) {
                itemData[0][lineitem]  = rs.getString("reference_no");
                itemData[1][lineitem]  = rs.getString("vendor_acc_no");
                itemData[2][lineitem]  = rs.getDate("date");
                lineitem = lineitem + 1;
            }

        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            connection.close();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    private void sendDataToSap() {

        System.out.println("Send Data to Sap");
        Table IT_LIST = null;
        Table IT_RESPONSE = null;

        try {

            if (rcount > 0) {

                handler.createRFCFunction("ZSL_SMS_PO_CREATION");
                IT_LIST = handler.getTablePara("IT_LIST");

                for (int x = 0; x < rcount; x++) {

                    IT_LIST.appendRow();

                    IT_LIST.setValue(itemData[0][x], "REFNO");
                    IT_LIST.setValue(itemData[1][x], "LIFNR");
                    IT_LIST.setValue(itemData[2][x], "EBDAT");

                }

                System.out.println(IT_LIST);

                handler.excFunction();
                IT_RESPONSE = handler.getTablePara("IT_RESPONSE");
                handler.releaseClient();

                int int_row = IT_RESPONSE.getNumRows();
                System.out.println("int_row " + int_row);

                if (int_row > 0) {
                    this.tableOparator(IT_RESPONSE);

                }

            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
            handler.releaseClient();
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        finally {
            rcount = 0;
        }

    }

    private void tableOparator(Table table) throws Exception {

        pooler = DBPool_POSMS.getInstance();
        dataSource = pooler.getDataSource();
        Connection con = dataSource.getConnection();
        con.setAutoCommit(false);

        qex = new DBTableQueryExcecutre(con);

        StringBuilder sbQuery = new StringBuilder("INSERT INTO tbl_created_po (reference_no,po_no) VALUES");
        System.out.println("COL -->" + table.getNumRows() + " records to insert for tbl_created_po");

        // --- create query ---------------------------------
        for (int i = 0; i < table.getNumRows(); i++) {
            // table.setRow(i);
            sbQuery.append("(?,?),");

        }

        sbQuery.deleteCharAt(sbQuery.length() - 1);
        sbQuery.append(";");
        qex.setUpdateQuery(sbQuery.toString());
        elements.clear();
        for (int i = 0; i < table.getNumRows(); i++) {
            table.setRow(i);

            elements.add(table.getString("REFNO").trim());
            elements.add(table.getString("EBELN").trim());

        }

        qex.updateInsertQuery(elements);
        con.commit();

        for (int i = 0; i < table.getNumRows(); i++) {
            table.setRow(i);

            String sbQuery2 = "update tbl_po_data set status = 'X', po_no = '" + table.getString("EBELN").trim()
                    + "' where reference_no  = '" + table.getString("REFNO").trim() + "';";

            int rcount = qex.runQuery(sbQuery2);
            con.commit();
            System.out.println("tbl_po_data Rows --> " + (i + rcount) + " Status Updated");

        }

        qex.closeConnections();
        con.close();
        System.out.println("Cycle Finished....");
        System.out.println("Connection Closed");

    }
}
```

My LogCat.....

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

The last packet successfully received from the server was 14,391,063 milliseconds ago.  The last packet sent successfully to the server was 14,391,344 milliseconds ago.
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:1121)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.send(MysqlIO.java:3871)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2484)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2664)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2809)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.setAutoCommit(ConnectionImpl.java:5333)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingConnection.setAutoCommit(DelegatingConnection.java:371)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.PoolingDataSource$PoolGuardConnectionWrapper.setAutoCommit(PoolingDataSource.java:328)
    at CreatePO.getItemFromDB(CreatePO.java:84)
    at CreatePO.run(CreatePO.java:52)
    at java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Timer.java:555)
    at java.util.TimerThread.run(Timer.java:505)
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset by peer: socket write error
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite0(Native Method)
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite(SocketOutputStream.java:109)
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.write(SocketOutputStream.java:153)
    at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flushBuffer(BufferedOutputStream.java:82)
    at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flush(BufferedOutputStream.java:140)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.send(MysqlIO.java:3852)
    ... 10 more
```

Comment: Try turning this into a minimally reproducible example. There's a lot of business logic in here that's unrelated to your issue.

Comment: Try to set autoReconnect=true and validationQuery=select 1 to the connection object